# php a good way to read from a file

Tags: php

i have a txt file with a list of country's. For my form i just read all the data in a select list line per line with fgets(). And that works fine except for some problems.

1) When i have a country with ¨ on a letter it comes in the list just as a blank.
2) When i put the data in an xml at the end it seams there is a return at the end of each value in the form of '&#xD'.

so my question. Is there either a way to fix these problems or is there a better way to read data from a file. Or should i use on other filetype then txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a trouble with the text encoding. You could try to run [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) on the text before echo:ing it out. Another solution is to use [utf8_encode](http://php.net/utf8_encode) or [utf8_decode](http://php.net/utf8_decode) (depending on which encoding your pages are served as, and on the encoding of the file).

Comment: the utf8 solves the first problem. But the return is still there.
using htmlentities() messes it up completely,

Comment: @unknown(google) htmlentities has a default charset ISO-8859-1, you may chnage that to utf8 if you are using it.

Comment: the i get things like 'bosni&euml'

Comment: &euml; is an HTML entity that is used to work around text encoding issues in web pages. You can skip htmlentities if it's not giving you the desired effect.

Comment: then there still is the return that doest go away.
My source looks like this:


<option value="Albanie
">Albanie</option><option value="Andorra
">Andorra</option><option value="Bosnië
">Bosnië</option><option value="Bulgarije
">Bulgarije</option>

Comment: I don't know what "return" you are talking about. Do you mean a newline?

Answer (score 0):

> In [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991109.html#charescaping), the carriage-return (#xD) character is represented by `&#xD;`

Just make sure that after you've read each line, you [`str_replace('\r', '', $line)`](http://php.net/str_replace) each line to remove the carriage-return character from the end of the line.

Comment: You could also use the `trim` function, which takes care of any whitespace, not just `\r`.